# Keep python global variables between function calls in excel using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I am working on a project using xlwings. I have a question, can I set global dynamic variables like pandas data frame or dict, list etc a live in the memory? Currently I found between different runpython VBA calls, the data frame seems to be lost. Anyone has an idea? Or do you have any recommendations on other plugins which can do that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that xlwings' `RunPython` VBA macro will start a new Python process each time it is called. This means that you cannot use global variables inside Python to share information between calls.

You could keep the data in the Excel file, for example in an extra sheet that you read and write from your Python script. Otherwise you will need to use a different data persistence solution, for example a separate file or a database.

Comment: The answer is basically correct but see [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/621) for the discussion/hack for the same issue that works on Windows only.